# How to set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength- 'System.OutOfMemoryException'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I know this is a duplicate question, but I tried all the things already.

Previously,when I found this issue, I follow some one's answer from stack overflow and it worked for me. The answer is below:

```
@{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    var jsonModel = serializer.Serialize(Model.ModelName);
}
```

and

```
 var model =@Html.Raw(jsonModel);
```

It worked for me. But **now my data size is more than 250k. In future, it will increase more** So '*OUT OF MEMORY EXCEPTION*' is thrown.

Now I tried

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

in

web.config file also. Still Its not working. How to set an unlimited maxjson length.?

Comment: as far as I know maxJsonLength is an integer. So it can't be unlimited and the maximum is 2147483644.

Comment: I tried this 2147483644 also .its not working. Got any other solution to fix this?

Comment: well you said that your first solution worked and the second doesn't. I think this indicates that you are using a controller for the json and not a webservice. which means that your 'serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;' is going to be the best you are going to get. Otherwise if you are sure about your webservice try closing the tag '<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"></jsonSerialization>' for some reason it worked with a few things for me that also shouldn't have a closing tag...

Comment: <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/> I add closing tag at the end by using /. Actually I can't get what u mean sir, but First solution worked for me  and its still working but for huge record only it thrown exception 'out of memory'. Is there any other way to fix it?@mrdeadsven

Comment: I don't think that there is a fix the way you are doing it right now. One of the things I did before and that might work for you is when you try to fetch the JSON, split it in smaller parts move the smaller parts through the jsonSerialization and paste them back together.

Comment: @mrdeadsven how to do the splitting through jsonserialization and paste back? got any sample?

Comment: unfortunately not this is what I did in a project several years ago for a company and I do not have access to the code anymore. Only thing I still know of it is that we pulled in the raw JSON somewhere locally, split it into multiple smaller package (we used a regex to split on a certain part of the JSON data so it is not random midway the JSON) gave those packages an ID (so you know the order to paste them back together) ran the packages through the serializer and pasted them back. I haven't used javascript or JSON in years so this is all the info I can provide.